# Is it legal for an Indian Citizen to travel to Nepal without any form of identification?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, driving, borders, nepal

I am an Indian Citizen and I wish to drive to Nepal. I am aware of the fact that if you enter Nepal by air, even as an Indian Citizen, you will be required to present an ID.

According to Wikipedia, Nepal has open borders with India underneath the [1950 Indo-Nepal Treaty of Peace and Friendship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_Indo-Nepal_Treaty_of_Peace_and_Friendship). Thus, Indian citizens do not require a visa in order to enter Nepal, but while traveling by road, is an ID required?

Comment: You've asked multiple questions in one post. Fortunately the link I've found seems to mostly cover what you're asking anyway, but in future please try to keep them to one question per post, or they may get closed :/

Comment: Ah! Indeed I have but they seem to be all pointing is the same direction. (Which is what I intended in the first place). Is it just that I have way too many question marks? :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, a form of ID is still required, otherwise how would you prove that you're an Indian citizen?  A Kiwi could rock up and say 'hi I'm Indian, I don't need a visa'.  However, it doesn't need to be a passport.

From the [Department of Immigration of the Government of Nepal](http://www.nepalimmigration.gov.np/page/information-for-indian-nationals-11):

> Identity documents required for Indian citizen going to/coming from
>   Nepal by Air:-
>
> Valid National passport. Photo Identity card issued by the Government
>   of India/State Govt./UT Administration in India to their employees or
>   Election ID card issued by Election Commission of India. Emergency
>   Certificate issued by Embassy of India, Kathmandu. Identity
>   Certificate issued by Embassy of India, Kathmandu. Persons in the age
>   of group of above 65 years and below 15 years would be exempted from
>   the requirement of approved identity documents mentioned at SL. No.
>   (i),(ii),(iii) and (iv). However, they must have some documents with
>   photograph to confirm their age and identity such as PAN card, Driving
>   license, CGHS card, Ration card etc. Children between the age group of
>   15 to 18 years may be allowed to travel between India and Nepal on the
>   strength of Identity certificate issued by the principal of the school
>   in the prescribed performa. In case of a family (family means husband
>   wife, minor children and parents) traveling together, the approved
>   identification document at SL. NO.(i) ),(ii),(iii) and (iv) would not
>   be insisted from all the family members if one of the adult members of
>   the family has in possession of one of the prescribed identification
>   document  at SL. NO.(i) ,(ii),(iii) and (iv). However, the other
>   family members must have some proof of their identity with photograph
>   and their relationship as a family viz. CGHS card, Ration card,
>   Driving license, ID card issued by school/college etc. Note:-
>
> Aadhaar (UID) card is not an acceptable travel document for travel to
>   Nepal/Bhutan. Certificate of Registration issued by the Embassy of
>   India, Kathmandu, Nepal to Indian nationals is not an acceptable
>   travel document for travelling between India and Nepal.   The
>   Emergency Certificate & Identity Certificate issued by the Embassy of
>   India, Kathmandu will be valid for single journey for travelling back
>   to India

Comment: But this says specifically that these restrictions apply when travelling *by air*. What if I don't travel by air?

Comment: Yes, and your question said " Are there any situations where I do not require a passport?" - the answer is yes, by air.  This is why you need to ask multiple questions separately, or clarify what you mean :/

Comment: Edited! Take a look again. Sorry for the confusion. :(