# Return stamp is missing (via train)

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, passport-stamps, nepal

I was travelling to Nepal on a flight and my passport was stamped. I returned back to Calcutta on a train and I didn't get a stamp when crossing the border.

Is that a problem?

Comment: Whose stamp are you worried about not having, departing Nepal or entering India?  What citizenship do you hold?

Comment: AFAIK there is no cross-border train between India and Nepal, generally you have to cross that border on foot. Did you stop by Nepali immigration on your way back (and just didn't get the stamp), or you forgot to stop by Nepali immigration as well? This could happen there; usually Indian passport control would send you back. If they didn't, you should be fine in India, but may have (minor) issues next time you enter Nepal.

Comment: @GeorgeY. - Actually there are cross border trains, but they don't go very far into Nepal, usually just the first bigish town.  But I haven't ridden them so not sure what immigration formalities there are at the border or nearest stations.  I know crossing from Bhutan into India by road at Samdrop Jongkhar you had to know where India Immigration was, since there was no "border" rather just a small building down a driveway behind a hedge.  Coming the other way, Bhutan's immigration is at a office downtown, not at the border.

Comment: Related: [Is it legal for an Indian Citizen to travel to Nepal without any form of identification?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/26082/3221)

Answer (score 1):

As [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/26084/3044) confirms (based on [the Government of Nepal website](http://www.nepalimmigration.gov.np/content/important-information.html)), there is not even a need for an Indian citizen to carry a passport when visiting Nepal. Therefore there is no reason why a stamp would be required when crossing any of the borders you crossed.

So no, this should not be a problem.